# Python pip3 egg_info error code 1 while installing Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.6

I have recently got python 3.6 and I am installing python packages. So far requests has worked but for pygame, I get an error:

```
 WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"
Using WINDOWS configuration...

Path for SDL not found.
Too bad that is a requirement! Hand-fix the "Setup"
Path for FONT not found.
Path for IMAGE not found.
Path for MIXER not found.
Path for PNG not found.
Path for JPEG not found.
Path for PORTMIDI not found.
Path for COPYLIB_tiff not found.
Path for COPYLIB_z not found.
Path for COPYLIB_vorbis not found.
Path for COPYLIB_ogg not found.

If you get compiler errors during install, doublecheck
the compiler flags in the "Setup" file.


Continuing With "setup.py"
Error with the "Setup" file,
perhaps make a clean copy from "Setup.in".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-xufd58ed\pygame\setup.py", line 165, in <module>
    extensions = read_setup_file('Setup')
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\distutils\extension.py", line 171, in read_setup_file
    line = expand_makefile_vars(line, vars)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\distutils\sysconfig.py", line 410, in expand_makefile_vars
    s = s[0:beg] + vars.get(m.group(1)) + s[end:]
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-xufd58ed\pygame\
```

I have had errors similar to this when installing other packages such as pandas
Could the error be that the packages are not yet ready for python 3.6 or somthing else?
I am running windows 10 64bit

Please help, Nic

Comment: better use `3.5` - there is nothing new in `3.6` what you need in PyGame.

Comment: i like to keep up to date with the python versions for example the new way to format strings in python 3.6 ect.

Comment: you like to keep up to date and now you have problem - wait awhile - 3.6 is too new to use it.

Comment: ill just wait to see if anyone else has a solution for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you.

### Setup

Go to this page: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame and download the `.whl` file that suits your **Python** *and* **Windows** version.

In my case it's `pygame‑1.9.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl` since I use **Python 3.6.0** and **Windows 64-bit**.

Next, enter `cmd` in the search box on your taskbar and press enter. A command window will open.

Enter the following into the cmd:

```
pip install setuptools
pip install wheel
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install --upgrade wheel
```

You then have two options when installing pygame:

### Option 1 - In Python Folder

Paste the file you downloaded earlier in the Python folder (*in my case it's* `C:\Python`).

If you downloaded `pygame‑1.9.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl`, install `pygame` with:

```
pip install pygame‑1.9.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

(Or else change `pygame‑1.9.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl` to the name of the file you downloaded, if it is different to mine).

Before you enter the previous command, make sure the file you downloaded is in the Python folder (*in my case*, `C:\Python\pygame‑1.9.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl`) and you copied the whole file name including the `.whl` extension or else it won't work.

### Option 2 - On Desktop

Paste the file you downloaded earlier on your desktop.

If you placed your `.whl` file on your desktop, enter this to change your current directory:

```
cd "C:\Users\(your_username)\Desktop"
```

Then, if you downloaded `pygame‑1.9.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl`, install `pygame` with:

```
pip install pygame‑1.9.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

(Or else change `pygame‑1.9.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl` to the name of the file you downloaded, if it is different to mine).

Before you enter the previous command, make sure you change your current directory and you copied the whole file name including the `.whl` extension or else it won't work

This should install `pygame` 1.9.2 and work on Python 3.6.0.

Comment: Thanks, although this site dose not have everything such as sklearn

Comment: sklearn? Use [scikit-learn](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn) instead.