# pygame Python 3.6 Installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm using Python 3.6, and I'm trying to download pygame, but I'm having trouble. I downloaded the right version, and I have `pip`; but I have an error when I try to use it.

```
>>> pip install wheel
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> pip install pygame‑1.9.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

this is what I tried, and it said that `install` is invalid syntax. I couldn't find an answer, and my skills with windows are poor, so I'd appreciate some help. Thanks :)

Comment: A complete post to installing pygame here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338451/python-pip3-egg-info-error-code-1-while-installing-pygame#41644582

Comment: You have to enter that in the Windows command-line not in the Python shell. Also, you don't need to install the whl file and can just download pygame from PyPI `pip install pygame` or explicitly for Python 3.6 `py -3.6 -m pip install pygame`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your command line and navigate to the whl file, then run the command again but not in the Python interpreter